# Cannot compare a string to a custom object?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I somehow need to compare my `NSString` from my `NSUserDefaults` to my custom object, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViews commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];

    NSString *todayString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.todayDate];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        //Delete from storage
        for (int x = 0; x!=-99; x++) {

            NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",todayString,x]];
            AG_Storage *someStorageObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
            AG_Storage *storeToArray = [[AG_Storage alloc]init];
            storeToArray.itemName = someStorageObject;


            NSLog(@"%@",someStorageObject);
            NSLog(@"%@", [self.mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

            //HAVE TO TURN mainArray TO A STRING
            if ([self.mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == someStorageObject) {

                NSLog(@"strings equaled, trying to delete...");
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",todayString,x]];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
                x=-100;
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Trying loop again...");
            }
            if (x>5) {
                x=-100;
                NSLog(@"ERROR BROKE");
            }


        }

        [self.mainArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableViews deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];


    }
}
```

I'm trying to delete something from both my running mutablearray, and the stored data you see. This is my log

```
2014-04-03 22:19:18.344 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] test
2014-04-03 22:19:18.345 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] <AG_Storage: 0x89627f0>
2014-04-03 22:19:18.345 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] Trying loop again...
2014-04-03 22:19:18.346 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] Test 2
2014-04-03 22:19:18.346 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] <AG_Storage: 0x89627f0>
2014-04-03 22:19:18.347 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] Trying loop again...
2014-04-03 22:19:18.347 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] testeisca
2014-04-03 22:19:18.347 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] <AG_Storage: 0x89627f0>
2014-04-03 22:19:18.348 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] Trying loop again...
2014-04-03 22:19:18.348 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL
2014-04-03 22:19:18.349 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] (null)
2014-04-03 22:19:18.349 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] <AG_Storage: 0x89627f0>
2014-04-03 22:19:18.350 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] Trying loop again...
2014-04-03 22:19:18.350 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL
2014-04-03 22:19:18.350 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] (null)
2014-04-03 22:19:18.351 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] <AG_Storage: 0x89627f0>
2014-04-03 22:19:18.351 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] Trying loop again...
2014-04-03 22:19:18.352 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL
2014-04-03 22:19:18.352 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] (null)
2014-04-03 22:19:18.353 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] <AG_Storage: 0x89627f0>
2014-04-03 22:19:18.353 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] Trying loop again...
2014-04-03 22:19:18.354 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL
2014-04-03 22:19:18.354 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] (null)
2014-04-03 22:19:18.355 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] <AG_Storage: 0x89627f0>
2014-04-03 22:19:18.355 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] Trying loop again...
2014-04-03 22:19:18.356 AgendaBk[60877:a0b] ERROR BROKE
```

Is there any way I can make `<AG_Storage: 0x89627f0>` a string again so I can compare the two and delete? If not, is there a suitable backup method? The frustrating part of this is I know what I'm not doing right, but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: not sure if this is in your code, but in objective-c, string equality is not handled by `==`, it is handled by `[string1 isEqualToString:string2]`

Comment: yeah I must have restored too early, it still doesn't work when I change that. Thanks for the reminder though!

Comment: An NSString is one kind of object, and an AG_Storage is (apparently) a different kind of object.  They will never be equal.

Comment: Solved it! used 

`AG_Storage *toDoItem = [self.mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSString *compare = toDoItem.itemName;
` and compared it that way. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @user3430084 please post your solution as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
AG_Storage *compareStorage = (AG_Storage *)[self.mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([compareStorage isKindOfClass:[AG_Storage class]] && [compareStorage.itemName isEqualToString:someStorageObject.itemName])
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: hmm no this isn't working either. 

`2014-04-03 22:36:33.839 AgendaBk[61001:a0b] test
2014-04-03 22:36:33.839 AgendaBk[61001:a0b] -[__NSCFString itemName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89bfc40
2014-04-03 22:36:33.842 AgendaBk[61001:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString itemName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89bfc40'`

Answer (score -1):

You can test and cast:

```
id someObject = [self.mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if([someObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSString *string = (NSString *) someObject;
} else {
    // unexpected error?
}
```

Comment: hmm what do you mean? I tried throwing this in before the loop and it wouldn't let me compare `string`.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. Casting an object from one class to another doesn't do anything in Objective-C. The data type for all objects is just `id`, which is simply a memory address number. Casting does noting, except tell the compiler to assume the object at that address is a specific class. It doesn't actually change the object to the provided class.

Comment: Correct, but it can make the IDE happy enough to let you write some code. If you want to call an NSString method on an object you get back from NSArray's objectAtIndex: method, for example, you need to clarify that it is indeed an NSString or you'll get an XCode warning. And it's a little misleading to say that the "data type for all objects is just id" -- it's true, but objects to have a *class* and can tell you what class they are.